# c++ boost::posix_time::ptime default value

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I have a member variable in my class:

```
class Foo
{
// ...
private:
  boost::posix_time::ptime t;
}
```

I want to initialize it in the constructor to a well known value such that I know it hasn't been set by the program yet:

```
Foo::Foo()
   : t(NULL) // doesnt work
{}
```

But setting it to NULL doesn't work because its not a pointer.

How do I initialize `boost::posix_time::ptime` to a well known value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default constructor initializes it to `boost::posix_time::not_a_date_time`.  There is a member function to check for that `t.is_not_a_date_time()`.  For more info see the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
  boost::posix_time::ptime t;
  Foo() : t() {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << foo.t.is_not_a_date_time() << '\n';
}
```

[Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AtxLHznBOFAoK0bj)